# TFS 2015 - Build vNext: "Access Denied: Project Build Service does not have write permissions for orchestration plan"

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm administering an On-Premise TFS 2015 (Update 1) installation, and we've migrated almost all of our builds to the TFS Build vNext system. Everything was going great until recently when our builds will suddenly and without warning start failing with an error:

```
Access denied: Project Build Service does not have write permissions for orchestration plan  xxxxx
```

This will even happen within minutes of a successful build on the same agent.

The first couple of times, I resolved it by just re-running the .\ConfigureAgent.ps1 with all of the same values and it would work from anywhere between a couple hours and a couple weeks.

Without any changes to anything permissions related or updates, this workaround has stopped working. The user for the build agents has not changed, and is the same user that runs the XAML build service which is still functional.

I have scoped the builds' Build job authorization scope to 'Current Project', I have confirmed that the build user is registered, a member of the Project Collection Build Service, and there are no non-default permissions.

I am completely at a loss as to why this area is so fickle and unstable.

Does anyone have any insight that could help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the instruction in this post to fix your issue: [Access denied for orchestration plan on Build](http://nkdagility.com/access-denied-orchestration-plan-build/)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that post many times. Following the instructions yielded no new results.

Comment: Although I didn't think it was as important, almost everything I run into references a similar error, but they all say "Project Collection Build Service" and my error is just "Project Build Service".  I don't know if that is an important detail or not.

Comment: @abest did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue and its project build service for me too.

Comment: @skundu No, unfortunately it was a transient error that would come and go. Sometimes it seemed related to any permission changes for any user access. Sometimes rebooting helped, but not every time. I ended up having to move my affected teams to brand new projects and ditch all of the history and artifacts of the old one. That was the only for sure fix I found.

Comment: @abest thanks. Can you state which version of tfs you are on? We are on TFS2015Update1 and want to know if this problem is addressed in Update3 or TFS15.

Comment: We upgraded this month to TFS 2017, but I do not recall seeing the issue in 2015 Update 3